# How to Move Highlighted Row using Up/Down?

Tags: jquery, laravel, tailwind-css

I've been trying to make table that can navigate to other rows using arrow key up/down. But when using up/down it only works once. After that the highlighted row is not moving and the input cannot be filled.

[image]

Do you know what's wrong with my code?

Thanks.

```js
var table = $('#transaksiKasir tr:last');
table.addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white');

$('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    table.removeClass('bg-slate-700 text-white');
    table.next().addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white')
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    table.removeClass('bg-slate-700 text-white');
    table.prev().addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white');
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="items-center w-full align-top border-gray-200 text-slate-500 mb-4" id="transaksiKasir">
  <thead class="align-bottom">
    <tr>
      <th class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold text-left uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
        Nama Barang
      </th>
      <th class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
        Harga Jual
      </th>
      <th class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold text-left uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
        Quantity
      </th>
      <th class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold text-left uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
        Discount (%)
      </th>
      <th class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold text-left uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
        Discount (Rp.)
      </th>
      <th class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold text-left uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
        Subtotal
      </th>
      <th class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold text-left uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
        Total
      </th>
      <th class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold text-left uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
        Action
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($listBarang as $barang)
    <tr>
      <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
        <p class="mb-0 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight">
          {{ $barang->barang->nama_barang }}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center p-2 align-middle bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
        <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
          {{ IDR($barang->barang->harga_jual) }}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
        <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
          {{ $barang->qty }}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
        <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
          {{ $barang->discount_persen }}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
        <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
          @isset($barang->discount_value) {{ IDR($barang->discount_value) }} @endisset
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
        <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
          {{ IDR($barang->subtotal) }}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
        <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
          {{ IDR($barang->total) }}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
        <button wire:click="$emit('openModal', 'kasir.edit-barang',{{ json_encode([" transaksiJualDetail " => $barang->id]) }})" class="py-2 mr-2 px-4 bg-slate-700 text-sm text-white rounded-lg hover:opacity-80 transition duration-300 ease-in-out shadow-sm">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-edit"></i>
                            </button>
        <button wire:click="deleteBarang({{$barang->id}})" class="py-2 mr-2 px-4 bg-red-600 text-sm text-white rounded-lg hover:opacity-80 transition duration-300 ease-in-out shadow-sm">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you want to move only highlights to another row, or you want to move whole row up or down and stay highlighted. And give us some HTML code for table. With that you can make it like working snippet (with very basic css)

Comment: yes i want to move the highlights to another row. edited the table code at the bottom

Comment: Please update the snippet demo above to include plain HTML and not your template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined that last row will be highlighted row, and when you move highlight to another row your last row is no more highlighted, and according to him you don't have starting point to move highlight again.

This is working solution:

```js
           // Your initial highlighting the last row
           var table = $('#transaksiKasir tr:last');
           table.addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white');

           $('body').on('keydown', function (e){
                e.preventDefault();

                // Take this values for every arrow key press
                if(e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38){
                   var table = $('#transaksiKasir tbody tr');
                   var table_row = $('#transaksiKasir tr.text-white');
                }
                // Down
                if(e.keyCode == 40){
                    // Stop at the last row
                    if(table_row.index() == table.length - 1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                    table_row.removeClass('bg-slate-700 text-white');
                    table_row.next().addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white')
                }
                // Up
                else if(e.keyCode == 38){
                    // Stop at the first row
                    if(table_row.index() == 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                    table_row.removeClass('bg-slate-700 text-white');
                    table_row.prev().addClass('bg-slate-700 text-white');
                }
           });
```

```css
.text-white {
  color: #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="items-center w-full align-top border-gray-200 text-slate-500 mb-4" id="transaksiKasir">
        <thead class="align-bottom">
            <tr>
                <th
                    class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold text-left uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
                    Col 1
                </th>
                <th
                    class="px-6 py-3 pl-2 font-bold uppercase align-middle bg-transparent border-b border-gray-200 shadow-none text-lg border-b-solid tracking-none whitespace-nowrap text-slate-400 opacity-70">
                    Col 2
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 1
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td
                    class="text-center p-2 align-middle bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 11
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 2
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td
                    class="text-center p-2 align-middle bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 22
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 3
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td
                    class="text-center p-2 align-middle bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 33
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 4
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td
                    class="text-center p-2 align-middle bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 44
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="p-2 bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-sm font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 5
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td
                    class="text-center p-2 align-middle bg-transparent border-b whitespace-nowrap shadow-transparent">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight">
                        Row 55
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: it works pretty well. thanks mate.